# How to check ssh directory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh

I would like to know what directory is being used by ssh to store known hosts and keys from inside a non-interactive powershell script.

I can only see the output from the script after it has completed.

i.e. I want to find out if it is `c:\users\some_user\.ssh` or `c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh` or something else.

If I run `ssh user@server -p port -v -v -v` then I do get

```
[17:53:28][Step 1/5] debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /.ssh/known_hosts
[17:53:28][Step 1/5] debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

But in a windows context what does `/` mean.

Comment: I'd like some kind of debug mode or something. I've tried setting all the usual fields `%HOME%`, `%HOMDRIVE%`, `%HOMEPATH% and %USERPROFILE%` buit none of that works. Or the name or an environment variable that can actually be set for the `ssh_config` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the value used is `$env:HOME` rather than `$HOME`.

This can be set using `setx HOME` while will be effective in the next Powershell you open or using `reg add HKCU\Environment /v HOME /t REG_SZ /d "/c/Users/james"` which will be active next time you log off / log on